# Get field value in MongoDB without parent object name

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm trying to find a way to retrieve some data on MongoDB trough python scripts
but I got stuck on a situation as follows:

I have to retrieve some data, check a field value and compare with another data (MongoDB Documents).
But the Object's name may vary from each module, see bellow:

Document 1

```
{
"_id": "001",
"promotion": {
    "Avocado": {
        "id": "01",
        "timestamp": "202005181407",
    },
    "Banana": {
        "id": "02",
        "timestamp": "202005181407",
    }
},
"product" : {
    "id" : "11"
}
```

Document 2

```
{
    "_id": "002",
    "promotion": {
        "Grape": {
            "id": "02",
            "timestamp": "202005181407",
        },
        "Dragonfruit": {
            "id": "02",
            "timestamp": "202005181407",
        }
    },
    "product" : {
        "id" : "15"
    }
}
```

I'll aways have an Object called `promotion` but the child's name may vary, sometimes it's an ordered number, sometimes it is not. The field I need the value is the `id` inside `promotion`, it will aways have the same name.
So if the document matches the criteria I'll retrieve with python and get the rest of the work done.

PS.: I'm not the one responsible for this kind of Document Structure.

I've already tried these docs, but couldn't get them to work the way I need.

[$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/)

[$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

Comment: If you are trying to retrieve Document 2, are you trying to get the ids of both the Grape and Dragonfruit?  Or just one?  If just one, how are you determining which one to pick?  If both, are you looking for an array with both id's to be returned?

Comment: I need the id from all documents.

Answer (score 0):

Try this python pipeline:

```
[
    {
        '$addFields': {
            'fruits': {
                '$objectToArray': '$promotion'
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$addFields': {
            'FruitIds': '$fruits.v.id'
        }
    }, {
        '$project': {
            '_id': 0, 
            'FruitIds': 1
        }
    }
]
```

Output produced:

```
{FruitIds:["01","02"]},
{FruitIds:["02","02"]}
```

Is this the desired output?